# Calling functions in another file

Tags: php

Am new to php, I am trying to call a function from another php file, but rather it's giving this error 'Call to undefined function myName()' and I have required the file.

This is the code

**Firstfile.php**

```
<?php
  function myName(){
    echo "Tammy";
  }
?>
```

**Secondfile.php**

```
<?php
require 'Firstfile.php';

   myName();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example how any file include with PHP

Php get current working directory

```
getcwd();
```

For example folder stracture

```
-project 
---model
---controller
-----controller1.php
-----controller2.php
---view
-config
```

If I want include controller1.php in any file I do it

```
$cwd=getcwd();

$path=$cwd.'/project/controller/controller1.php';
include $path;
```

How I can do see your folder structure ?

1- you can create autoload function with [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

2 - you can create autoload with [psr-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md)

Answer (score -1):

your code looks fine but are you sure you are calling the function from **Secondfile**, and also check if you already saved the **firstfile.php** after adding the function to it, sometimes we forget to save the file before running it.

Comment: this should be a comment